# How can I stop this JavaScript from mistakenly adding 'active' the root '/' links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using this JavaScript to automatically add 'active' CSS to the navigation bar link for the current page, but it also constantly adds 'active' to the home page '/' link.

How can I prevent this?

```
var url = window.location;
var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
}).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
if (element.is('li')) {
    element.addClass('active');
}
```

For example here I am on the Orders page but it has also added `active` to the Dashboard link `/`.

[image]

Comment: Well, I don't see how that would happen with your code... Are you sure "active" is not added somewhere else?

Comment: The filter function is not working properly... recheck.

Comment: @OctavZlatior You can see in the screenshot that it adds `active` to the root link `/` (Dashboard) even when I'm not on that page.

Comment: oh, I misunderstood the problem, sorry

Comment: but yes, your filter function is the problem - if your current url is "/orders" and the dashboard url is "/", the indexOf will return 0: "/orders".indexof("/") is 0 :)

Comment: Ok but what is the correct way? :|

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your links won't contain query strings nor fragment identifiers. Notice that `window.location.href` can be like `http://example.org/page#contact`.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href === url || url.substr(0, this.href.length) === this.href && /\W/.test(url.charAt(this.href.length));
}).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
if (element.is('li')) {
    element.addClass('active');
}
```

Also note that `/page/2` is equal to `/page` in my example. You can view how it works in my [unit tests](http://jsfiddle.net/ujtx8vzj/).